# Hero banner image not working css and html

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Mountains</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
        <style>
            /*css stylization*/
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            header{
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                padding: 10px 50px;
            }
            .logoname{
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .logo img{
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .navlinks{
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            .navlinks li{
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .navlinks li a{
                transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: roboto;
            }
            .navlinks li a:hover{
                color: aquamarine;
            }
            /*hero image code*/
            .herobanner {
                background-image:url(/image/herobanner.jpg);
                width: 100%;
            }
            .herotext {
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                color: #000;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <figure class="logo">
                    <img src="\image/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </figure>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="navlinks">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">GALERY</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div class="herobanner">
                <span class="herotext">
                    <h1>LIVE HIGH</h1>
                </span>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I have made a simple navigation bar and under it I want to put a hero banner under it, the image URL does not work and the image does not get displayed but the text gets centered as the code for class='herotext' works properly.

please help me out with the code. Thanks to everyone who took their time out to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hero div has no content inside it which means the height is ZERO(The span positioned absolute so its height will not calculated), just add a 'min-height' and it will work:

```css
        /*css stylization*/
        
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        header {
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px 50px;
        }
        
        .logoname {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        
        .logo img {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .navlinks {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        .navlinks li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
        .navlinks li a {
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: roboto;
        }
        
        .navlinks li a:hover {
            color: aquamarine;
        }
        /*hero image code*/
        
        .herobanner {
            background-image: url(https://www.artonicweb.com/learn/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/12-HERO-IMAGES-1024x536.jpg);
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 500px;
        }
        
        .herotext {
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            color: #000;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mountains</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <figure class="logo">
            <img src="\image/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </figure>
        <nav>
            <ul class="navlinks">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GALERY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="herobanner">
        <span class="herotext">
                    <h1>LIVE HIGH</h1>
                </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you just use this **

```
.herobanner {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/17/18/03/lights-5310589_960_720.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
 .herotext {
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   color: #000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your code that the .herobanner don't have any height because you defined the position of the span element inside it as absolute so you have several options to fix this either by removing the absolute position so the height of .herobanner will be based on the content or define a fixed height for it.
See the example below:

1st option

```
            .herotext {
              text-align: center;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              color: #000;
             }
```

2nd option

```
            .herobanner {
              background-image:url(/image/herobanner.jpg);
              background-size:cover;
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              width: 100%;
              height:20vh;
             }
               and repositon the span element so it fits inside it
```

i prefer the first solution so it will take the height of it's content.

codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/OJXyWrv